# How to customize window menu (linux ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, menu, customization, gnome

I'm looking for a way to add a new shortcut (lets say "kill this window") into the window menu:

[image: Window Menu]

Is it possible, under gnome/ubuntu?

Thanks!

PS. Edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: A comment from who downvote it would be polite. I spent 50 points in a bounty on this question, its funny someone come here and take 2 more for an unknow reason.

Comment: They didn't like your question.  That's reason enough to downvote.  I'd have downvoted because this is not programming related, AFAICT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu which is being displayed (what can be seen from the screen shot) is the part of the **Window Manager decorations**. The menu options which you see depends on the window manager which is being run. Generally it is possible to add custom key bindings (key combinations like Alt+F4 etc. Please note key bindings are not the same as short cuts on your desktop panel) for the window (again depends on the window manager), but to add any new option/item into the menu you will have to modify the source code of the window manager, build it & use the customized window manager. So far I have not come across any window manager which allows adding custom menu options without rebuilding the source

If you are using Gnome session on Ubuntu, it is highly likely that you are running **metacity** window manager (not sure about KDE session as I do not use it)
In case of metacity, key bindings can be checked in gconf entries under /app/metacity (using either gconftool-2 --dump options or gconf-editor). You can refer the following link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/
If you want to add new menu options then you will have to rebuild metacity from the source as far as I know. In the source code of metacity, files under src/ui can be particularly useful for your need.

Answer (score 1):

another.anon.coward is right, this menu is drawn by the window manager (metacity in Ubuntu, most probably) , not by your application.

Your best option is probably to make your window undecorated (`gtk_window_set_decorated(w, FALSE)` if you use GTK, for example), and then draw the title yourself, and add your menu. And move the window and resize it (if needed), etc.

That is more or less what Chromium/Chrome does, and it works kind of right. Most of the time. But then, if you are searching for a way to kill a hung window, it will not work, because, well, the window is hung.

But note that in linux most people won't search for custom options in the window menu, for obvious reasons, so I'd recommend you to look for another GUI solution.

Answer (score -1):

not 100% what you're looking for but close i think, you can add a shortcut to [xkill](http://ubuntuguide.net/quickly-close-windows-and-applications-using-xkill-in-ubuntu), which allows you to select which window you would like to kill..

Comment: Ok, but, how do I add a shortcut in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: `right click` + `Add to Panel` + `Custom Application Laucher` + `Name: xkill` + `Command: /usr/bin/xkill` + use an icon you find fitting, voila :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks, but that is an off-topic answer. I want to customize the window-menu if that is possible at all. (BTW, I already have this shortcut and it is very useful, thx).

Answer (score -2):

If you do not like `xkill`, I am afraid but you have to take `chromium` source code and expand the menu and build your own browser.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no connection with browser. Window menu appears on every window, just right click the title bar.

Comment: I'm afraid I need to! ;) But I still hope someone here can have a clue, at least what file to edit. I googled a lot about this. Well, if google gives also answers pointing to stackoverflow, I hope soon we will have our answer here, bringing new users to this nice site.

Comment: It would be great if someone can do the homework and tell you *how* _exactly_ you can do it. But I doubt that.